# Is it possible to add edge resistance to Compiz "Desktop Wall" edge flipping?

Tags: compiz, launcher, workspaces

Example: I have four workspaces vertically, which I want to switch between by simply moving the cursor to the bottom or top part of the screen. But sometimes I want to click something in the bottom part of the screen, and I 'accidentally' switch workspace instead.

Can I add edge resistance, like the 'Reveal sensitivity' in the Launcher?

If this isn't a feature, how can I request it, or possibly write the code myself? And if I will write the code, do you have any idea where I can get inspiration (e.g. the Launcher) or should write the code (e.g. which files in 'Desktop Wall')

Comment: I've also tried changing <nodelay> to false as per http://forum.compiz.org/viewtopic.php?t=12558
but that didn't make a difference either.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems that edge resistance is unsupported, I decided to find an alternative solution:   edge clicking

**This method also has the added benefit, that Snapping Windows will still work.**

If you don't need the ability to move windows (e.g. dragging window to new workspace), just use Desktop Wall section 'Bindings' under 'Move within wall'. You can map edge clicking to actions there.

If you need to move windows easily, by the following method, you can left click the edge to move up/down, or right click to move with window up/down:

(Make sure Desktop Wall is enabled)

1. Setup Button bindings

[image]

2. Setup commands

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the settings manager you can edit the 'edge trigger delay' in general optoins, for example, try 250.

Comment: I tried with values of 250, 1000, and 5000, but it didn't seem to have any effect. Do I need to restart or should the effect be immediate after removing focus from the text field?

Comment: The effect should take place immediately after entering some value. But maybe you can try a restart...

Comment: I tried setting it to 1000 and restarting, but that didn't help. Does it work on your setup? There is no edge trigger delay even when the value is set to 1000.

Comment: Is your ubuntu machine up to date? Otherwise, I can't think of any other solution...